# Useful plants to grow in garden

Tags: food, gardening, fruits-and-vegetables

I am a guy living in **Kerala, India**. I have a plot of 5 [cents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cent_(area)) (about 200 square meter) in my backyard. I would like to know which plants would be helpful for planting in the plot (edible fruits or vegetables), that require less care in a later stage after planting them. 
My intention is to grow them for daily use like cooking.

Comment: This question is way too broad as it stands. If we consider edible uses, a good place to start is by making a list of what you would like to eat. It makes most sense to work backwards - what do you want or need and then go and find the plants that fit the bill. It is tempting to go through lists of useful plants and draw up a long list of things that seem interesting, but there's no point growing a weird and wonderful array of plants if you are not going to use them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be a better fit over on [gardening.SE](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/)